# using regex to filter parenthesises with exceptions

Tags: text, filtering, regex-negation

I am using Python re and want to filter a text and drop all parenthesis except those matching `(.)`, I have written this Regex `'((?!\(\.\))[()])'` using negative look ahead, but it is still grabbing the `")"` closing parenthesis for `(.)`

any ideas how I can correct this please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This pattern worked for me: `\((?!\.\))|(?<!\(\.)\)` (example here: https://regex101.com/r/jK5wU3/5).  This selects:

1. all "(" not followed by ".)", and
2. all ")" not preceded by "(."

NOTE: It occurs to me you may not have meant the literal string "(.)", but rather meant "all content inside balanced parenthesis".  If this is the case, regex is likely not the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

The regex gets to ), executes the lookahead, which fails, and eats the bracket.

Try this, I feel it is clearer using two steps.

```
victim = re.sub(r'\( (?=.[^)])',  '', victim, re.X) # Strip (
victim = re.sub(r'(?<=[^(].) \)', '', victim, re.X) # Strip )
```

Comment: Note that because . matches brackets ()) will be pass through. The . can be replaced if this is not desired.